# Slow UNC paths on virtual Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, tcpip

We have a virtualized Windows Server 2008R2 running on a host Windows Server 2012R2.  The 08R2 server is also running SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 (Version 10.5) and IIS 7.5.

Lately we've had intermittent issues with running SSRS on this server, which is referenced in our ERP software as "http://servername/servershare".  At the same time, we've had issues connecting to the server directly via RDP, and accessing any UNC shares on the server.  We can connect to the server with Hyper-V manager, and accessing SQL server doesn't seem to have any issues.  We also run reports with separate software on another server, and it doesn't seem to be affected by these delays.

From my understanding, the way SSRS is accessed, RDP, and UNC shares all make use of TCP/IP.  Even accessing UNC shares while on the server in question is still slow, compared to simply browsing the file structure through Windows Explorer normally, and this would lead me to believe that I have an issue with TCP/IP on this server.  I have found some suggestions, such as disabling Large Send Offload, disabling IPv6, checking drivers, although I have yet to find anything that resolves this issue.  I am reluctant to believe it is anything with the virtual switch or physical interface, since both of these are shared by another virtual machine that is not experiencing any of these issues.  The main difference between these two machines is that the other is running 2012R2.

Is there anything we should consider checking at this point?  Are we correct in believing this to be related to either IIS, or TCP/IP, or both?

Answer (score 0):

So after more deliberation and waiting, we finally decided to proceed with rebuilding the TCP/IP stack.  After uninstalling and reinstalling, we now had problems with DNS resolution on the server, where it would only use itself for DNS, and wouldn't query anywhere else for DNS resolution.  Our solution ended up being to reinstall Server 2008 R2.  On the plus side, we have had no issues with any of the problems we were experiencing previously, so whatever the issue was seemed to be core to Windows itself.